# Should the filename + extension be included as part of a Canonical Tag

Tags: url, seo, canonical-link, index.html

I've been reading about canonical tags but can't find a definitive explanation as to whether the file extension should be included in the canonical tag.

I have three files in the root folder and Google console tells me the not all pages have been
indexed.  Google says:

> Duplicate without user-selected canonical.

So how do I tell Google crawler that `index.html` is the master version?

In the examples I've seen, there has been no mention of the filename just folder names.

In my example I a fictitious site below:
`https://portfolio-website.example/index.html`

Should the canonical in the `index.html` header be:
`<link rel="canonical" href="https://portfolio-website.example/index.html" />`

Is this the pattern to use for every `.html` file?

Answer (score 0):

`index.html` should never be part of your URLs. It should be omitted from your canonical URL.   `index.html` is supposed to be a hidden file that powers the request for the directory.  Users are never supposed to know that you have it because it is ugly and unnecessary to put in the URL.

That means that when you choose the canonical for your home page, it should be: `<link rel="canonical" href="https://portfolio-website.example/">`

When you link to your home page, you should also omit the `index.html`.  The easiest ways to link to your home page without it are `<a href="/">` (root relative link, works from within your site) or `<a href="https://portfolio-website.example/">` (absolute link.)

`index.html` is the only HTML document that should be treated this way.  If you have another page (like `foo.html`) the document name and extension would go in the canonical URL (and in links).

Comment: now I'm beginning to understand canonicals.  However I've also read about self referential canonicals. Say I have these files a.html, b.html, c.html.  Should I put a canonical in each file and include the document name and extension?   If this is the case and assuming Google decides the b.html and c.html are near enough duplicates then how do I tell Google that b.html is the version to use?  I'm slightly confused about that.  I've done a lot of research but I'm still confused.

Comment: Canonical URLs usually resolve issue with near total duplication.  If you copied `b.html` to `b-test.html` and changed a few words, you'd probably want to set the canonical on both versions to point to `b.html`.

Comment: Here is a very relevant question that I answered that provides more info: [Should query strings be included or removed from the canonical tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/114622/should-query-strings-be-included-or-removed-from-the-canonical-tag)